# Python matplotlib subplot clumsy datetime xticks issue

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

I have subplots with shared x,y axis. The x-axis is datetime stamp. Everything looks fine. The problem is x-axis looks clumsy.

My code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols,sharey=True,sharex=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.025, wspace=0.05)
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        #### plot data goes here. 
        ax[i,j].autofmt_xdate()
        ax[i,j].xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation = 30)
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.95)
plt.show()
```

Present output: The x-axis labels look clumsy, hard to read.

[image]

Comment: First make sure your dates are not strings.  You can rotate the text as per the link above.  You can also use ConciseDateFormatter https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html

Comment: @JodyKlymak Yes! My dates are indeed in `dtype='datetime64[ns]'` format, not string. Also, I edited my question. Now, the labels are rotated. I need to reduce their frequency.

Comment: Your plot is too small while you try to force the dates as xticks. try passing `figsize=(20,10)` to subplots.

Comment: You are right. I played with the size. It solved the issue. Thanks